# Ignore area in ScrollView for scrolling interactions

Tags: python, scrollview, kivy

Assume I have this UI adapted from the `ScrollView` example:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.slider import Slider
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class ScrollViewApp(App):
    def build(self):
        layout = GridLayout(cols=1, padding=10, spacing=10,
                size_hint=(None, None), width=500)
        layout.bind(minimum_height=layout.setter('height'))
        for i in range(15):
            blt = BoxLayout(size_hint=(None, None), size=(480, 40))
            blt.add_widget(Label(text="Slider %d" % i))
            btn = Slider(value=i, min=0, max=42, size=(400, 40),
                         size_hint=(None, None))
            blt.add_widget(btn)
            layout.add_widget(blt)
        scroll = ScrollView(size_hint=(None, None), size=(500, 320),
                pos_hint={'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}, do_scroll_x=False)
        scroll.add_widget(layout)
        return scroll

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ScrollViewApp().run()
```

Due to `scroll_timeout`, interactions with the `Slider`s are delayed. Is it possible to define areas in the `ScrollView` in which `touch` events are just passed through to children without the delay (and without initiating a scroll)?

Comment: *waits for a captain* I wanted something similar a year ago, no success. I think this may not be even implemented. But just to be sure, ask on irc.

Comment: @KeyWeeUsr see my answer below, this seems to work for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with a simple override of `ScrollView`'s `on_touch_down`, which so far seems to satisfy my needs. The idea is to test whether a touch event falls into an 'exclusion zone' (in the example below only the x dimension is checked, but it'd be trivial to extend this to arbitrary rectangular areas). If it does fall into that exclusion zone, the `on_touch_down` event will be dispatched to the `ScrollView`'s children. If a child captures it, the event is swallowed. In all other cases, `super.on_touch_down` will be called, i.e. normal scroll behaviour is initiated. That has the benefit of still being able to scroll if the touch does not land on a `Slider` (in the question's example).

```
class MSV(ScrollView):
    x_exclusion_lower = NumericProperty(None, allownone=True)
    x_exclusion_upper = NumericProperty(None, allownone=True)
    x_exclusion = ReferenceListProperty(x_exclusion_lower, x_exclusion_upper)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        pos_in_sv = self.to_local(*touch.pos)
        if (self.x_exclusion_lower is not None or self.x_exclusion_upper is not None) and (self.x_exclusion_lower is None or self.x_exclusion_lower <= pos_in_sv[0]) and \
                (self.x_exclusion_upper is None or self.x_exclusion_upper >= pos_in_sv[0]):
            touch.push()
            touch.apply_transform_2d(self.to_local)
            if self.dispatch_children('on_touch_down', touch):
                return True
            touch.pop()
        super(MSV, self).on_touch_down(touch)
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Widget touch event bubbling](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#widget-event-bubbling).

I've never had to do the same thing as you but maybe you could create a custom class that inherits `ScrollView` and override `on_touch_down` event where you could:

1. Disable scroll
2. Call `super.on_touch_down`
3. Enable scroll.

Another way might be creating a custom widget that inherits `Slider` class that the user clicks. Then overload it's `on_touch_down` method with `return True`. [Documentation says](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#widget-touch-event-bubbling):

> In order to stop this event bubbling, one of these methods must return True

`ScrollView` also fires `on_scroll_start` event so maybe you could do something similar there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Martin. I knew I had to tamper with `on_touch_down`, but didn't quite know how. Seems like I found a way (which is different from your suggestion).